# Node + Passport, Error: Authentication strategies must have a name

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, saml

I'm trying to initialize a SAML strategy during the require line. Something like this:

```
var myStrat = new require('passport-something').Strategy(
    { .... }
);
passport.use('something', myStrat);
```

but am getting the error:

```
.../passport/lib/authenticator.js:54
  if (!name) { throw new Error('Authentication strategies must have a name'); }
               ^

Error: Authentication strategies must have a name
    at Authenticator.use ...
```

or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Authenticator.use` if a custom strategy name is not defined: `passport.use(myStrat);`

.

I've had it like this (which works):

```
var mySomething = require('passport-something');
var myStrat = new mySomething.Strategy(
    { .... }
);
passport.use(myStrat);
```

but I wish to change it because I need to call passport-saml's `Stragety.generateServiceProviderMetadata()` function later on.
Which (I think) mean I need a variable pointing to the new Strategy instance.
Not a big deal I know, just would like to have the code for this particular strategy look more in line with the rest if I can. Which all look like:

```
var GoogleStrat = require( 'passport-google-oauth2' ).Strategy;
passport.use('google', new GoogleStrat(
    ....
));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this should work:

```
var myStrat = require('passport-something').Strategy(
    { .... }
);
passport.use('something', new myStrat());
```

or, if you want to hold the instance:

```
var myStratInstance = new (require('passport-something').Strategy)(
    { .... }
);
passport.use('something', myStratInstance);
```

Comment: What is meant by **if you want to hold the instance**? Please elaborate your both given examples.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan he very likely meant "hold the created instance". In the first example `myStrat` is not exactly the strategy, it is the function that creates the strategy. In the second one `myStrat` is the created strategy. I think there is no practical difference between the two.

Answer (score 5):

in NEST.JS don't forget to check, from where did you import the Strategy

Example:

`import {Strategy} from 'passport-local'` ===> true

`import {Strategy} from 'passport'` ===> false

Answer (score 3):

// provide a name for your strategy like this in this portion of your code

import { PassportStrategy } from "@nestjs/passport";
export class JwtAuthStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, ''){

}

// in nest js

Answer (score 1):

I got this error.
if you got this line of code in your code

**"passport.use(user.createStrategy);"**

make sure to change to this.,

**passport.use(user.createStrategy());**

hope this is useful for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you have this line of code:

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy);
```

Then Change it to:

```
passport.use(User.createStrategy());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem like this
First you defined on the top

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

then you change the code

```
passport.use(User.authenticate());
```

to

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
```